# Google OAUTH gives 502 error

Tags: django, api, http, oauth

I am successful in authenticating users locally, but on the production server I am receiving 502 errors after timeout..

here is my FLOW:

```
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        user_agent='Real_Hub/1.0',
        redirect_uri='quickerhub.com',)
```

locally redirect_uri is simply my localhost ip and it works fine.

here is my error through chrome network panel:

```
quickerhub.com
GET
502
Bad Gateway
text/html
```

Comment: Not a solution, but you likely don't want to share your client secret to the public :)  I suggest removing it and replaying it with stars or something.

Have you tried making the redirect_uri include 'http'

Comment: Did you figure this out? would be nice to share the solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

This likely has to do with your redirect_uri. 502 is a very general error. It indicates that Django (probably uWSGI or Passenger) was unable to get a response before timeout. Have you tried that uri directly in your browser? If you have any HTTP authentication or anything on that domain, it will cause this error. For some reason, the OAuth does not seem to be properly creating the redirect response.

Hope this helps!